# Developing a bioinformatics APP that identifies DNA seq with a barcode at the front

Tags: python, barcode, bioinformatics

I am working on an assignment for introduction to python class and I am having a lot of trouble writing my script to read my file and then identify a barcode at the beginning of a sequence in a file.

this what I have to open my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import sys  

fname  = sys.argv[1]

handle = open(fname , "r")
# read the file # 
for line in handle:
        print line.strip()

handle.close()
```

and it works perfectly to open my file and prints the contents to the screen.

the issue I have is adding on to this to complete the assignment I am getting an error message and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I will be grateful for any help or suggestions.

The assignment and the correct expected results and detailed:

Create an executable file called ~/assignments/assignment07/assignment07.py

The python script should take 2 command-line arguments (in order):

(1)a DNA barcode
(2)the name of a file containing DNA sequences

Your script should print all DNA sequences in the sequence file that match the given barcode at the beginning of the sequence, but throw away the barcode. Do not print the barcodes, just the sequences that match the barcodes, and do not match barcodes that aren't at the front of the sequence.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys
barcode  = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[2]

bclen = len(bacode)



handle = open(fname, "r")

# read the file # 

for line in handle:

        print line.strip()


for line in filename:

        bc    = line[4:][:bclen]

        seq   = line[4:19][bclen:]



        if bc == barcode:

                seqslice = sequence[4:]

                #print "barcode %s is at beginning of sequence %s" % (barcode, seqslice)



handle.close()
```

Comment: And you don't know what error message you get -- or, you do but don't wish to share it?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: when I run the script: ./assignment07.py assignment07.dataTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./assignment07.py", line 6, in <module>
    fname  = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Is it important in Python to only use variables that are properly declared? There is no mention of `fname` before its first use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script is full of some common beginning errors (mismatched variable names and not understanding the use of slices) but here is a corrected version with notes that should help:

Worked running with `python script_name.py 123barcode filename.csv`

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys
barcode  = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[2]

bclen = len(barcode) #fixed typo so from bacode
handle = open(filename, "r") #changed from fname

# read the file # 
## Combined for loops, no reason for double loop here

for line in handle:
    print line.strip()

    bc    = line[:bclen]  #changed to just slice of beginning to barcode length
    seq   = line[bclen:]  #from end of barcode to end (only want 19 just add)

    print "BC = " + bc    #Added these print statements: when problems occur
    print "SEQ = " + seq  # always look to see what variable actually contain

    #I don't know what you wanted here but this prints the matching sequence
    if bc == barcode:     
        print "barcode %s is at beginning of sequence %s" % (barcode, seq)
handle.close()
```